# How to hide CodeIgniter ci_session display on browser client (firebug)?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just notice that CodeIgniter store session as Cookies, the problem final user could see easily our array session even encrypt `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;`, i feel not safe.
I want like raw php  $_session it is not display on client side browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not save session data client side. In `application/config/config.php`, set `$config['sess_use_database']` to `TRUE`. This will save all session data in a database.

You will need to make sure you enter your DB connection settings into CI, and make sure the table `ci_sessions` exists in your database.

[CI User Guide - Sessions Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: No better solution store in database?

Comment: Alternatively, if you store session data **encrypted** in cookies, there is no way it can be tampered with. The only issue with this is that cookies have a 4kb size limit.

Comment: the link giving 404

Answer (score 0):

Store the session into a database.